# How do I make a bar chart go in descending order in R?

Tags: r

I provided an image of the code I already have, but how do I make it in descending order?

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example:  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example> with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: library(forcats) fct_reorder() https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_reorder.html

Answer (score 5):

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
          type = c('Ave', 'Blvd', 'Cirle', 'Court', 'Dr'),
              total = c(254, 25, 30, 35, 550)
)

ggplot(data = df, 
       mapping = aes(x = fct_reorder(type, total),  y = total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = '#112446')+
  theme_bw()
```

[image: sample]

add  .desc = TRUE to fct_reorder for descending

```
ggplot(data = df, 
       mapping = aes(x = fct_reorder(type, total,  .desc = TRUE),  y = total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = '#112446')+
  theme_bw()
```

[image: sample]